# Capturing screenshots on background

Tags: android, android-studio, service

I'm using [ShotWatch](https://github.com/abangfadli/shotwatch) to capture screenshots events.

The included example only works while inside the aplication, but I want to capture the event and launch an Activity. My code seems to ignore the service.

The mainfest has all the services/activity defined.

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        // run-time permissions
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            // You can directly ask for the permission.
            // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
            Toast.makeText(this, ":(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // You can use the API that requires the permission.
            Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScreenshotCaptureService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenshotCaptureService:**

```
public class ScreenshotCaptureService extends Service implements ShotWatch.Listener {
    private ShotWatch shotWatch;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        this.shotWatch = new ShotWatch(getContentResolver(), this);

        this.shotWatch.register();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        this.shotWatch.unregister();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenShotTaken(ScreenshotData data) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(AddActivity.CAPTURE_PATH, data.getPath());
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

**AddActivity:**

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String CAPTURE_PATH = "ADD_CAPTURE_PATH";

    private ImageButton imageButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        Uri captura = Uri.fromFile(new File(getIntent().getStringExtra(AddActivity.CAPTURE_PATH)));

        this.imageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        this.imageButton.setImageURI(captura);

        this.imageButton.setOnClickListener((View v)->{
            // ...
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;

        switch (requestCode) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your service will only run for a minute on Android 8.0+. It would need to be a foreground service to run for longer. Also note that your library has not been updated in years, will not work correctly on the latest versions of Android, and makes assumptions about where devices will place screenshots.

Comment: @CommonsWare as fas as I know, there's no event for screenshot event, so it's the best I've found (and it works, at least for me)

Comment: "there's no event for screenshot event" -- correct. "and it works, at least for me" -- so long as you are the only one who will use the app, that is all you need. Your problems will begin if you want others to use the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

I was using 'startService' instead of 'startActivity' inside onScreenShotTaken, on ScreenshotCaptureService.